# "Cannot Get /" Error when try to access /about route

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, web-applications

I try to made another route for my 'web-educational-only' it works when the route is '/' but when i try to linked in with 'about' page, it's show 'Cannot Get /about'

here's the code for app.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.set('views','./view');
app.use(express.static('assets'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index.ejs');
});
app.get('/about', (req, res) => {
    res.render('about.ejs'); 
});

app.listen(3000);
```

and here's for about.ejs (the file is in view folder):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>About</title>
    
    <script src="/send_url.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<h1>It's About the Page</h1>
<p class="alert">made for educational only</p>
</body>
</html>
```

can you see what's the problem there? thank you

Comment: Did you restart the Node.js program after changing its source code?

Comment: @Quentin Oh my... I forgot to do that, thank you very much!!
(edit: should i delete this question or not?, it's my first question here)

Comment: @DimasAlfiansyah You can answer on your own question. Write down how to solve it. Other people could be helpful by your posts.

Comment: @Jain other people already do, but thanks for advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you make any change in any file of your project then restart your server every time
use nodemon package in your project so that after making any changes in file you won't have to manually restart the server, nodemon will detect changes and restart your server every time you make any change